# In Apex, do standard objects have a namespace (or something similar) to disambiguate them from a subclass with the same name?

Tags: apex, namespace

I have a class in Apex with a subclass called `User` (describing users of an system external to Salesforce). In one of the parent class's methods, I need to access the global `User` class, like so:

```
global class myClass {
    global class User {
        // stuff
    }
    global List<User> myMethod () {
        List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE <criteria>];
        return users;
    }
}
```

In this simplified example, the code fails to compile on the `List<User>` line with the error "Illegal assignment from List<User> to List<myClass.User>". Is there a namespace I can use or some other way to tell Apex that the `User` in `List<User>` refers to the global `User` object?

Comment: see also https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_prefix.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All standard namespaces are actually sub-namespaces of System. The SObject objects (e.g. Account, Contact, MyObject__c) are classes belonging to Schema. System is a reserved identifier, meaning you cannot "shadow" it by naming a class or variable System.

You'll want to read [Namespace, Class, and Variable Name Precedence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_precedence.htm) which describes how the compiler works at a simple level:

> Because local variables, class names, and namespaces can all hypothetically use the same identifiers, the Apex parser evaluates expressions in the form of name1.name2.[...].nameN as follows:
>
> 1. The parser first assumes that name1 is a local variable with name2 - nameN as field references.
> 2. If the first assumption does not hold true, the parser then assumes that name1 is a class name and name2 is a static variable name with name3 - nameN as field references.
> 3. If the second assumption does not hold true, the parser then assumes that name1 is a namespace name, name2 is a class name, name3 is a static variable name, and name4 - nameN are field references.
> 4. If the third assumption does not hold true, the parser reports an error.

Basically, local variables take precedence over items that are "further up" the scope chain.

You'll want to read more about [Using the System Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespaces_and_invoking_methods.htm) to learn about how you can use System to resolve to shadowed built-ins, but basically, it means you use System to reach the right class.

For example:

```
Decimal math = 25;
math = System.Math.sqrt(math);
```

However, you should *always* avoid doing this. Don't use class names like Math, Database, or Schema, because you'll break your code when it recompiles, and you'll have to use System everywhere. This is just plain tedious and error-prone.

Similarly, to reference an SObject, you can [Use the Schema Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_schema_namespace_using.htm) to find the correct object:

```
Integer user = 5;
Schema.User[] users = [SELECT Id FROM User LIMIT :user];
```

Obviously, this is pretty confusing, so you should avoid doing that. The more likely scenario is you'll do something like this:

```
Account Account = new Account();
// Later in your code
Account.SObjectType.getDescribe(); // Compile error?!
```

In this case, you can fix it by adding Schema:

```
Account Account = new Account();
// Later in your code
Schema.Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
```

But again, this is only confusing and should be avoided.

The worst case scenario is making a variable or class named Schema and another that shadows an SObject. You will then effectively be unable to use that SObject for the entire scope that this situation applies to.

Make your life easy and *avoid* doing this. Use more descriptive names for your variables, like "currentUser", "primaryAccount", "contactRecord", etc.

Comment: Listen to - "What does the fox say" - well this for starters!

Comment: I'm stuck with the class name as-is, so I'll give using `Schema` a try. Incidentally, if I had a nickle for every time I ran across something like `Account account = new Account();`, I would have an inconveniently large pile of nickles.

Comment: @asgallant - You are never 'Stuck' with a class name, just changing it may be more painful for some depending on the situation. If you can change it I would recommend you do so but only you can determine what is the best route now that you have the information to make the decision

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here, but my understanding is that anything with a global scope or annotated as a RemoteAction cannot be renamed or removed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes classes can have namespaces but that is not your issue...

In general it is a BAD idea to name a class the same as an sObject

For example and common one that causes issues

```
public class test{}
```

In the above example if you try to user test.starttest() (system class test with the startTest method) it will fail saying that startTest does not exist since you have defined a class named test as well

Since User is an sObject, there is confusion when you try to instantiate the List since there is also an sObject (and class) called user already...

It is trying to assign the Users object records to the Local Users class since that is what is there first and takes priority or something like that

There is a more technical answer that I am sure someone will post, but the takeaway is to **not name a class the same as existing standard classes**

For clarity, this would work but is also NOT advised

```
global class myClass {
    global class User {
        // stuff
    }
}

global class helperClass{

    global List<User> myMethod () {
        //This works because it is not in the same class as the subclass user
        List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE <criteria>];
        return users;
    }


}
```